# Implement tree structure. Store nodes in vector and denote children with indices? Or store nodes on the heap and use pointers to the children?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, memory

I have to implement a tree structure in C++ (a trie to be exact). It's on the hot path and will presumably get very big (hard to give an expectation, maybe around 1mio nodes).
Therefore, I am currently thinking about how to implement the structure as efficiently as possible. I have two ideas in mind:

1. The first is rather straight forward: Allocate all nodes on the heap, manage the pointers and denote the children of a node via pointers to the objects on the heap. However, I'm afraid that the repeated allocations (calls of new) will be slow. Of course, fidelling around with raw pointers is always a little dangerous and cumbersome as well.
2. The second idea would be to store all nodes in a pool. I would use a vector which holds all nodes. The children of a node would be denoted by a set of indices into this vector. Therefore, we could reserve 1mio nodes at the start of the program and have arguably very few resizes. However, when there would occur resizes, they would obviously be immensely expensive.

How would you suggest to approach the problem? Which downsides weigh heavier?

Great thanks in advance!

Comment: Are some node deleted? If yes, are they additional node allocated after that? More generally, what is the typical workload/usage of the data structure? Is the data structure used in a parallel context?

Comment: There are no nodes deleted. Only nodes added on a very irregular basis. That is, there might be branches which are hundreds of levels deep but only branch to 1 or to children at each level. On the other hand, it might as well have thousands of branches on the first few levels and only thin out later.
Edit: No parallel contxt.

Comment: 32 bit Indexes give ~2x more info density than 64 bit pointers. If you really want to push it, you can use 24 bit indexes in `char[3]` (up to 16,777,215 nodes), but then you have to be super careful or you can easily accidentally lose the savings due to padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard efficient C++ way of doing that is to write your data structure without worrying about how data are allocated, and use a dedicated **allocator template parameter** (like `std::vector` or `std::map`). This method helps to keep your code maintainable (thanks to *separation of concerns*) and be still quite efficient (thanks to templates). With this solution, you can first write your code easily (with the approach n°1) and then optimize allocations easily too (using for example the approach n°2).

Regarding the optimization of allocation: yes, `new` & `delete` could be slow (despite some platforms do this very efficiently).
Since there are no node deleted, you can use a very fast **[monotonic arena/stack-based allocator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region-based_memory_management)**
(you can take a look to [`std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/monotonic_buffer_resource) that seems to do that). The idea is to stack small allocated memory regions in memory chunks. Chunks can be pre-allocated or allocated on the fly one by one (possibly using a growing policy, but without resizing data). The chunk pointers can be stored in a very-small data structure (possibly fixed-sized array). When your data structure is deleted, you just need to delete the few chunks (you could even recycle them in loops). This strategy should be cheaper than your second approach, since resizing a vector is quite expensive. For more information, you can look the [CppCon 2017 talk of John Lakos on Local ('Arena') Memory Allocators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZNd5FjSquk).